# Error when I run a Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a `dockerfile`

[image]

After I run `sudo docker build .` I try to run the code `sudo docker run 4f6b94d826db`

This happens:

[image]

Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Could you replace image with text?

Comment: @aerokite Actually I couldn't. Stack is blocking when I write the code. It says there is much code and I must write more about it.

Comment: Please include code instead of images of code.  Don't **bold** or *italicise* random words as this adds nothing and causes distraction.

Comment: @lebelinoz I can't include code instead of images because stackoverflow doesn't let me do it. It says there is too much code and I must add more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try add the `libstdc++6` to your `apt-get install`.